# Add custom link in customer account navigation

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I want to add custom link in customer's navigation.I have developed below code but getting **404 - not found** issue while click on the tab.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="module">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/customer/list</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Data</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Then I create a controller file name : List.php at modulename/controller/customer

```
<?php
    namespace namespace\modulename\Controller\Customer;
    use Magento\Sales\Controller\OrderInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

    class List extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
     /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Customer order history
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
        public function execute()
        {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('My Data'));

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer.account.link.back');
        if ($block) {
            $block->setRefererUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        }
        return $resultPage;
    }
    }
```

Block file at namespace/module/block/customer/test/list.php

```
<?php

namespace namespace\modulename\Controller\Customer;

use Magento\Sales\Controller\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class List extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
 /**
 * @var PageFactory
 */
protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * Customer order history
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
 */
public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('My Orders'));

    $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer.account.link.back');
    if ($block) {
        $block->setRefererUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    }
    return $resultPage;
}
}
```

and add xml file : modulename_test_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="modulename">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">modulename/customer/list</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Data</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: were you able to resolve it?

Comment: check if your frontname and route Id are same.

Answer (score 0):

The path is not `modulename/customer/list` , but `route_id/customer/list` , where `route_id` is what you have defined in `routes.xml`. Coincidentally they can be the same, but is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your routes.xml with "frontName" same 'modulename'.
2. If it is not working. Pls run command setup:di:compile